# Bitlocker on a laptop without carrying around recovery key

Tags: windows-8, laptop, bitlocker

We have a rule in my company that all PC drives must be encrypted with BitLocker, including laptops.

My own Windows 8 laptop has a tendency to hang at shutdown, black screen but the computer never stops. I'd say it happens 25% of the time on average. The problem is, I then have to stop it manually and when it reboots I get the "Bitlocker blue screen of death" asking me to enter the recovery key.

If I have the key at hand everything then goes back on track, but I'm carrying this computer around everywhere I go, including places I don't have access to my company's network where the key is stored.

I understand the recovery key can be used to decrypt the drive, so I imagine it is not safe to have it with me all the time. I'm tempted to store it on my cell phone though, because if the laptop fails on me in the middle of nowhere/abroad/at a client's/on a train I have no other choice except calling someone at the office to give with the key - which I don't know if they'll be willng to do.

How can I deal with that problem ? Is Bitlocker really a sound option for a mobile device considering today's hardware failings (SSD drives, miniaturization and all that stuff) ?

Comment: So the real issue here is that your computer doesn't power down correctly. Why not attempt to fix that first?

Comment: I'm currently looking into this, but just because I find what the failure is doesn't mean I can easily fix it. Plus, other hardware failures could happen. My question was more general : since Bitlocker prevents me from booting when I would otherwise have been able to, can we say that Bitlocker is "fragile" ? Is it really a mature technology ?

Comment: @guillaume31 [BitLocker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitLocker_Drive_Encryption) was first introduced in Windows Vista and was later improved. What's the laptop exact model? Are the drivers certified for Windows 8? Providing the recovery key will only handle the symptoms, but won't prevent the actual problem from happening in first place.